# Can evolutionary biology processes be mathematically described?

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, applications

Action movies are full of violent combat, pursuiting and dangerous Scenarios. I think that the Evolution of mankind lead to such a behavior. It may be that selection processes have lead to the fact that under some circumstances human beings can be very violent and do ignore most of risks of the Environment (e.g. large heights). I mention concretely this, because I have seen that a book author has claimed that mathematica Evolution theory would describe the Evolution of violence.

Can evolutionary processes be modelled with mathematics?

I think yes, we can maybe use stochastic process theory. Are there some scientific results about how Evolution can be mathematized? Maybe Fokker-Planck equations?

Comment: Action movies are not exactly accurate portrayals of how real people behave.  But indeed, people sometimes do stupid and violent things.

Comment: As for your question, [Evolutionary biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_and_theoretical_biology#Evolutionary_biology) is indeed one of the main branches of mathematical biology, and there are lots of mathematical models for evolutionary processes.

Answer (score 2):

The theory of population genetics summarises microevolution with the [Price equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_equation#Statement). Game theory can identify the [evolutionarily stable strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionarily_stable_strategy) for behaviour.